# Prevent deletion of old compiled CSS file when there is a error in SASS files

Tags: sass, terminal, compiler-errors, node-sass

If there is a import error in sass the already compiled css file gets deleted. How to prevent this behaviour? So if error is encountered SASS shouldn't delete the old compiled css file.

It says deleted `user.css`. I wanna prevent that

[image]